# Eliminar elementos HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día gente, vuelvo nuevamente a ustedes con una nueva consulta.

Tengo una función que me genera unos `cards` de Bootstrap, hasta acá todo bien.
Esta función es llamada por un botón al final de un formulario.

```
function Cargarcc (a, b, c){
    cards1.remove();
    cards2.remove();
    cards3.remove();
    let x = (c == 'S') ? 'resource/media/logo-Santander.png' : 'resource/media/logo-HSBC.png';

    if(a == 0){
        b.forEach(function (element, index) {
            contCards.innerHTML += `<div class="cards col-4 align-self-center m-2" id="card${index}">
            <div class="imgCard"><img src="${x}" alt=""></div>
            <div class="txtCard"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum laboriosam ut, dolorum iste exercitationem atque! Excepturi velit, mollitia, provident porro voluptate unde aut fugit, sint corrupti impedit quis. Corporis, minus! </p></div>
            <div class="valor"><b>$ ${element}</b></div>
        </div>`
        });
    }else{
        b.forEach(function (element, index) {
            if(index === a){
            contCards.innerHTML += `<div class="cards col-4 align-self-center m-2" id="card${index}">
            <div class="imgCard"><img src="${x}" alt=""></div>
            <div class="txtCard"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum laboriosam ut, dolorum iste exercitationem atque! Excepturi velit, mollitia, provident porro voluptate unde aut fugit, sint corrupti impedit quis. Corporis, minus! </p></div>
            <div class="valor"><b>$ ${element}</b></div>
            </div>`
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

Esta función genera cantos `cards` como sean necesarios. Los primero 3 `cards` que se remueven, son a modo informativos cuando carga la web, cuando se generan los nuevos `cards` se eliminan.
El tema es que posteriormente si se modifica el formulario y se vuelve a presionar el botón, me elimine los `cards` que se generaron en un principio.

Intenté con esta función pero me elimina todo, pero cuando vuelvo a darle al botón para volver a generar nuevos `cards` no se ven. Pero si llamo `contCards.children.length` para ver que contiene me dice que tiene por ejemplo 0 al momento de borrar y al darle al botón me devuelve la cantidad de `cards` generados nuevamente, pero no los logro ver.

```
function borrarCards(){
    for(let i = contCards.children.length; i >= 0; i--){
        contCards.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Quedo a la espera de sus respuestas, para ver si logro solucionarlo. Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: en tu for prueba con `let i = contCards.children.length - 1;` o `contCards.innerHTML=""` en tu función `Cargarcc()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que basta con limpiar contCards, haciendo `contCards.innerHTML=""`

```
function Cargarcc (a, b, c){
    contCards.innerHTML =""; //<-- esta línea
    let x = (c == 'S') ? 'resource/media/logo-Santander.png' : 'resource/media/logo-HSBC.png';

     b.forEach(function (element, index) {
            if(a == 0 || index === a){
            contCards.innerHTML += `<div class="cards col-4 align-self-center m-2" id="card${index}">
            <div class="imgCard"><img src="${x}" alt=""></div>
            <div class="txtCard"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum laboriosam ut, dolorum iste exercitationem atque! Excepturi velit, mollitia, provident porro voluptate unde aut fugit, sint corrupti impedit quis. Corporis, minus! </p></div>
            <div class="valor"><b>$ ${element}</b></div>
            </div>`
        });   
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirve! Solo que la agregue en la función  borrarCards() porque si la agrego donde me indicas, solo me deja 1 solo card. Porque esto seria un simulador de cuotas para créditos y por cada vez que se le da al botón de simular carga 3 líneas de bancos diferentes y solo me deja la ultima. 

Acepto la respuesta, gracias por ayudarme a resolver el problema de mi código, a seguir practicando.